# Google Script to Copy Cell to Another Cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for a script that only runs when a cell in column 7 is edited.  There are multiple sheets so I want to specify which sheet it runs on.  When the user edits a cell in column 7, there is a popup asking a Yes/No questions.  If they answer No, the script runs.  I need the script to copy the data in that cell to column 9.  If they answer Yes, the script does not run.  Here is what I have so far...I can get the popup to work; however, I do not know how to get the "copyData" formula to work and I am hoping for help on that.  Thanks!

```
function onEdit2(){
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Current Seniority" ) {
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 7) {
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var response = ui.alert('Is employee being placed on leave?', 
ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
 // Process the user's response.
 if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
   Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
 } else {
      copyData();
   Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
 }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your current code works as expected and you are only having issues with the part of copying the data from one cell to another. If so, what is the criteria that you want to use to copy the data. Where are you copying it from exactly and where do you want to copy it to?

Comment: @FernandoLara Yes I get the popup but I do not have a working script for copyData().  I want to copy the data in column 7 cell to column 11 cell.  So for example if I edit cell H12...I should get the popup Yes/No...if I answer No, the value I entered in H12 should be copied to K12.

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const ns = ["Current Seniority","Sheet0"];
  const idx = ns.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if (~idx && e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {
    e.source.toast("Gate");
    let resp = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Is employee being placed on leave?', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if (resp == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.NO) {
      //copyData();
      Logger.log(`The user clicked "No" or the close button in the dialog's title bar.`);
    } else {
      Logger.log('The user clicked no')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This did not work.  Hopefully, my comment above clarifies.

Comment: Did you create an installable trigger?

Comment: Does your copyData() work?

Comment: You can rename it onEdit if you don't have any others you also my wish to look at executions to see the Logger output

Answer (score 0):

#### Try the following code:

```
function onEdit2(){
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Current Seniority" ) {
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 8) {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var response = ui.alert('Is employee being placed on leave?', 
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
      // Process the user's response.
      if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
        Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
      }
      else {
        copyData(r, s);
        Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
      }
    }
  }
}

function copyData(data, ss)
{
  var val = data.getValues();
  var newColumn = ss.getRange(data.getRow(), data.getColumn()+3);
  newColumn.setValue(val);
}
```

Make sure to add the trigger to the function so it runs on an edit or a change.

#### This is how it works:

[image]

#### References:

- [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)
- [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: I changed the column from 7 to 8 because you mentioned that you wanted the values from H to be copied on K